# Remove string start from certain character?

Tags: php, html, arrays

For example I have an array

```
$array[] = ['name - ic'];
```

The result I want is

```
$new_Array[]=['name'];
```

How do I remove the string that start from the `-` since the name and ic will be different for everyone? Anyone can help?

Comment: "Different for everyone" how? Have you looked at [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: okayy thankss. I will look into explode, I think it will works

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode` method you can split string into array.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $array[] = ['name - ic'];
    $array[] = ['name - bc - de'];
    $new_Array = array();

    foreach($array as $key=>$values){
        foreach($values as $k=>$val){
            $str = explode("-",$val);
            $new_Array[$key][$k] = trim($str[0]);
        }
    }
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function for the same.

```
$array = array('name - ic','abc - xyz','pqr-stu');
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $obj):
    $temp = explode('-',$obj);
    $newArray[] = trim($temp[0]);
endforeach;
print_r($newArray);
```

**Result**

```
Array ( [0] => name [1] => abc [2] => pqr )
```

Let me know if it not works.